# SQLite error on update: index out of range

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I use the following code to update an item in my SQListe database:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FIELD_NAME, place.getName());
    values.put(FIELD_LAST_SAVE_TIMESTAMP, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);

    int affected_rows = db.update(TABLE_PLACES, values, FIELD_ID + " = '?'",
            new String[] { place.getId() });
```

I get the following error:

```
01-14 14:50:52.261: E/AndroidRuntime(26535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 14:50:52.261: E/AndroidRuntime(26535):
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x27984c8
```

Do you have any idea?

BTW, this is hard to debug because I can't get the final sql statement shown. Is there a way to enable verbose logging somehow?

Comment: I really wonder why such a normal question gets a downvote. Why would you not make a comment instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` must not be quoted. Remove the `''` so it is not treated as a literal `'?'` but as a placeholder for literals.

The exception says that the number of `?`s and bind args do not match.

Comment: Well, thanks! But the ID returned from place.getId() is alphanumeric. I am supposed to put it into quotes. Do I need to double the quotes? I mean ''?'' instead of '?'

Comment: No need to quote yourself when using `?`.

Comment: Oh, ok. So quoting is handled by the update() function itself. I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

maybe the value (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L) exceed the FIELD_LAST_SAVE_TIMESTAMP maximum value